# Qual diferença entre o App.conf e o Web.conf?

Tags: asp.net, web.config, app.config

- Quais as diferença entre o *`App.conf`* e o *`Web.conf`*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Neste tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412552/differences-between-app-config-and-web-config), o autor da resposta comentou:

> Web.config e App.config
>
> A escolha do nome do arquivo de configuração é determinada pelo ambiente de hospedagem que você escolher para o serviço. Se você estiver usando o IIS para hospedar seu serviço, use um arquivo Web.config. Se você estiver usando qualquer outro ambiente de hospedagem, use um arquivo app.
>
> No Visual Studio, o arquivo nomeado App.config é usado para criar o arquivo de configuração final. O nome final efectivamente utilizada para a configuração depende do nome do assembly. Por exemplo, uma montagem com o nome "Coho Winery.exe" tem um nome de "Coho Winery.exe.config" arquivo de configuração final. No entanto, você só precisa modificar o arquivo app. As alterações feitas para o arquivo são feitos automaticamente para o arquivo de configuração do aplicativo final em tempo de compilação.
>
> Em usando um App.config, arquivar o sistema de configuração mescla o ficheiro App.config com o conteúdo do arquivo Machine.config quando o aplicativo é iniciado e a configuração é aplicada. Este mecanismo permite que as configurações toda a máquina a ser definido no arquivo Machine.config. O arquivo App.config pode ser usado para substituir as configurações do arquivo Machine.config; você também pode bloquear as configurações no arquivo Machine.config para que eles se acostumar. No caso Web.config, o sistema de configuração mescla os arquivos Web.config em todos os diretórios que apontam para o diretório do aplicativo para a configuração que será aplicada.

Veja a documentação no site da Microsoft [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Conforme [resposta em inglês no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412552/differences-between-app-config-and-web-config/1412568#1412568):

> Web.Config é usado para projetos web asp.net / serviços web.
>
> App.Config é usado para Windows Forms,  Windows Services, aplicações de console e aplicações WPF.

Ou seja:

- Se seu aplicativo está hospedado com IIS,  use web.config.
- Se sua aplicação for Windows, use app.config.

Usamos Web.Config em projetos asp.net web ou serviços web, e App.Config usamos em aplicações Windows Forms, Windows Services, aplicativos de console e e WPF.